# Notepad Regex Change order of Sentence using notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

Actually I'm not a pro, just noob. so If you give me detail info then I really appreciate your help :)

I want change sentence order.

Original Sentence

PrintClientMessage(null, "God mode has been disabled on \x03" + survivor.GetName());

**Result What I want**

```
PrintClientMessage(null, "\x03: -God mode" + survivor.GetName());
```

Also "God Mode" can be others word like Tree and Water, Laser sight, Man and Woman Etc.

So can you tell me command that include any word like "[A-Z]+" (IDK if it'll work nor not :D I told you I'm not a pro )

What I tried but didn't work:

```
(PrintClientMessage\(null,) ^(\w+) (has been disabled on) (\x03)
```

Comment: What are the relations between `Type 1`, `Type 2` and the expected result?

Comment: Ok then Don't mind 'em just Think about Type 2, I want to change type 2 order like (null, "God mode has been disabled on \x03" + Target.GetName()); --->>> PrintClientMessage(null, "\x03: -God mode" + survivor.GetName());

Answer (score 0):

If your messages are uniform and there are no other special expressions in your text then this is the simplest expression to use:

```
"(.+) has been disabled on (.+)"
```

You should replace it to this:

```
"\2: -\1"
```

Notice that you need to add parentheses only to the groups you want to *capture* (use later). If you want more accurate matches then you should also add the remaining parts of the text but you need to escape the regex control characters in your own text (like you did with the parentheses: `\(`).

You can try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/2X1QUG/1/

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is very helpful if you need to write and test regular expressions. It also explains what a regex means on the top right pane. Be aware that there are many *flavors* of regex which have slightly different syntaxes. [Notepad++'s syntax closely resembles PCRE](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) which I also set on the webpage.

Comment: thx a lot really helpful advice

Comment: Notepad++ uses Boost library that have some (minor) differences from PCRE.

Comment: Sure, sure, we should be as accurate as we can. Thanks. Fixed.